# Subtract a row of prices in one dataframe from columns in another

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, subtraction

I have a dataframe with 163 columns with unique names, say (x1, x2, x3, x4 ....) each of these columns has a series of returns (0.248, -0.00384, etc).

```
**DF1**
 x1       x2      x3     x4    .....
0.248 -0.00384  0.0394 0.0053  .....
```

In another dataframe I have one column with a list of the same unique names (x1, x2, x3, x4 ...) and another with a list of numbers (0.005, .001, etc).

```
**DF2**
x1 0.005
x2 0.001 
x3 0.005
x4 0.0005
...
```

My ultimate goal is to return a dataframe with the 163 columns (x1, x2, etc) with each columns net returns (so the x1 column is the original returns subtracted by 0.005, x2 column is the original returns subtracted by 0.001, etc).

So far I tried sorting the second dataframe, transposing and using unlist to get a vector of numbers, which I could then subtract from each column (but I cant figure out how to subtract from each column). Any help with figuring out how to do this would be really helpful. The list of unique names in the second dataframe are the same as the first dataframe, which is also sorted alphabetically, so it doesnt need to be matched up (both sorted will line up).

Comment: Are these in the same order?

Comment: Yep, once sorted they are in the same order. Just trying to figure out how to subtract the first price in DF2 from the entire first column in DF1, second price in DF2 from the entire second column in DF1, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, the colnames of `DF1` and rownames of `DF2` are not in the same order, you can use `match`

```
 DF1-DF2[match(colnames(DF1), rownames(DF2)),1][col(DF1)]
```

Should work if either or both datasets are not in the same order. For example

```
 set.seed(65)
 DF1N <- DF1[,sample(colnames(DF1))]

 DF1N-DF2[match(colnames(DF1N), rownames(DF2)),1][col(DF1N)]
```

If they are in order

```
 DF1-DF2[,1][col(DF1)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DF1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(40*10), ncol=10,
             dimnames=list(NULL, paste0("x", 1:10))) )
set.seed(42)
DF2 <- data.frame(Col1=rnorm(10, 0.01))
row.names(DF2) <- sample(paste0("x",1:10))
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. I was clearly over thinking this one, the match function works well and didnt realize it could return vectors right into the brackets as row numbers. Really helpful lesson to learn.

Comment: @Trevor Nederlof No problem.  I used `[col(DF1)]` to replicate each value of `DF2[,1]` so that element-by-element subtraction occurs or else we have to rely on the recycling.

Comment: Ah yes, was about to say that, when I tested it, was using the wrong prices for certain ones since it was recycling the vector (setting it like this would take each prices from the entire column  in DF1). Thanks again, really great solution.